# Editing .bst file to modify printing of publisher and address information

Tags: bibtex, formatting

I'm lost in some bst hell.  Basically I'm trying to get Springer's [`spbasic.bst`](http://trac.assembla.com/soray/browser/user/Henry/publications/AGILE%202011/svmult/styles/spbasic.bst?rev=281) file to work.  I'm almost there, but there are few annoying issues.
First, instead of getting `Address: Publisher`, I get `Publisher, Address`. which is incorrect.

I saw the functions `format.publisher.address`, and the `book` section:

```
FUNCTION {book}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
      editor format.key output
      add.blank
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  format.date "year" output.check  
  new.sentence
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.bvolume output
      format.edition output
  new.sentence
      format.number.series output
      format.publisher.address output
    }
    {
  new.sentence
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.doi output
  format.url output
  format.note output
  format.eprint output
  fin.entry
}
```

How do I fix it?
The `bst` syntax must be one of the least comprehensible languages I've ever seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

publisher and address are formatted and printed by the function 
`format.publisher.address`

```
FUNCTION {format.publisher.address}
{ publisher "publisher" bibinfo.warn format.org.or.pub
}
```

As you can see this function calls another function `function.org.or.pub`

```
FUNCTION {format.org.or.pub}
    { 't :=
      ""
      address empty$ t empty$ and
        'skip$
        {
          t empty$
            { address "address" bibinfo.check *
            }
            { t *
              address empty$
                'skip$
                { ", " * address "address" bibinfo.check * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
```

As you can see, there is one instruction `", "` (at line 1044 of the file `spbasic.bst`). This is what you have to modify, specifically, youcan replace it with `": "`.

Comment: Thanks! My biggest problem is on the position of address and publisher, which need to be swapped. What do I need to change for that?

Comment: change `publisher` to `address` and `address` to `publisher` in the body of the two functions.