# BibTex trouble: publisher/address location and removing fullstops

Tags: bibtex

I have the same problem as at [Editing .bst file to modify printing of publisher and address information](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84000/editing-bst-file-to-modify-printing-of-publisher-and-address-information) but I just don't get the solution.

When Guido writes "change publisher to address and address to publisher in the body of the two functions" It simply doesn't work.

I have taken:

```
FUNCTION {format.org.or.pub}
{ 't :=
  ""
  address empty$ t empty$ and
    'skip$
    {
      t empty$
        { address "address" bibinfo.check *
        }
        { t *
          address empty$
            'skip$
            { ", " * address "address" bibinfo.check * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

And turned it to:

```
FUNCTION {format.org.or.pub}
{ 't :=
  ""
  publisher empty$ t empty$ and
    'skip$
    {
      publisher "publisher" bibinfo.check *
      t empty$
        'skip$
        { publisher empty$
            'skip$
            { ":  " * }
          if$
          t *
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

and not only am I stuck with the ", " but there is no change in the position of the publisher and address.

I have also changed

```
FUNCTION {format.publisher.address}
{ publisher "publisher" bibinfo.warn format.org.or.pub
}
```

to:

```
FUNCTION {format.publisher.address}
{ address "address" bibinfo.warn format.org.or.pub
}
```

Must I change `format.publisher.address` to `format.address.publisher`?

Another question: My Journal names look like "J. Funny. Names." and I need them to look like "J Funny Names". All my bib entries are entered with the fullstops after the abbreviations. Can I tell BibTeX to remove them some how?

I found some code "remove.dots" which works well for author names but not for journal names. My code reads:

```
{
      journal
      remove.dots
      "journal" bibinfo.check
      "journal" output.check
      format.vol.num.pages output
    }
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please indicate *which* bibliography style you employ (and wish to modify). Better yet, please post a one- or two-entry bib file with contents you're trying to get typeset in a certain way.

Comment: Nevermind... I'm an idiot and stuffed up the Bibtex entry... Thanks for asking for a bib entry else my stupidity would have remained undiscovered.

Comment: In that case, we will probably mark this posting as "closed".